# why does cassandra report higher disk usage than i can see on the system?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have a 3 node cassandra cluster (running cassandra 3.5, in ec2), with a replication factor of 3, that has been in production for almost 3 weeks. There is one column family, and it looks something like this:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history_items
( person_id text, 
id_type text, 
client_id text, 
history_item text, 
activity_ts timestamp, 
primary key ( (person_id, id_type, client_id), activity_ts) )
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (activity_ts DESC);`

There are only 2 queries that run against this - one to insert (always with a ttl of one week), and one to read (always limit to 100). For a while, the dataset was increasing steadily, which I expected. I also expected it to level off after one week, because that is how long each piece of data lives, but it did not.

I am using graphite for monitoring. On Friday, the amount of data jumped up from ~17G on each node to ~23-27G per node. Today, I found that the nodes are now reporting ~115G-200G per node! `nodetool status` shows similar numbers, however, when I look at actual disk usage on these machines, it shows only ~20G on each. Until now, graphite stats (looking at 'Storage.Load' and 'TotalDiskSpaceUsed'), `nodetool status`, and `df -h` all showed more or less the same numbers.

What can explain the huge discrepancy between what cassandra is reporting, both to graphite and via `nodetool status`, and what I see on the machine?

I started running `nodetool repair` for the first time today, and it has slowed to a crawl. It has been running for about 6hrs now, and `nodetool compactionstats` shows that the 'validation' compaction has reached 48.95% progress. The total bytes 'completed' seems to continue increasing, but at a slower and slower rate, to the point that % progress has not increased (even .01%) for a few hours now.

Was running `nodetool repair` the right response to this? If it is, is there some other issue with the schema that could cause it to take so long? Since this is time series data, it seems like I should use 'DateTieredCompactionStrategy', but it is not clear to me that this would help the problem I am seeing.

Happy to share any other details that could help troubleshoot the issue.

EDIT:
It has been about 24hrs now, and the 'validation' compaction has only reached 49.02%. `nodetool status` and graphite are both showing between 115G-300G storage used, but `df -h` shows ~22G.

EDIT:
After replacing the nodes with larger boxes (c4.large -> c4.xlarge), I still see similar issues. Restarting cassandra on each node seemed to fix the incorrect reporting of 200G+, but `nodetool compactionstats` still shows some things I don't understand during a repair:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-2-163:~$ nodetool compactionstats -H
pending tasks: 1
- act_hist.product_views: 1

id                                   compaction type keyspace table             completed total   unit  progress
903cc350-58f2-11e6-8721-f377ed1bf63f Validation      act_hist product_views     2.48 TB   5.23 TB bytes 47.47%  
Active compaction remaining time :   0h00m00s
```

Where does that 5TB come from? When I run `nodetool compactionstats` during a normal (non-repair, so not validation compaction) compaction, the numbers seem much more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the increase after started running repair? How are you running repair?
What you are seeing is probably a result of repair making snapshots which are just hardlinks in this case and your monitoring tools are counting them in disk usage.

Comment: I noticed the increase first, then started running the repair via `nodetool repair` (nodetool cli), thinking it might help